# What is the need for smoothing the cosmological density field?

Tags: cosmology, structure-formation

I have recently started reading about the Press-Schechter formalism in cosmological structure formation, but what I still do not understand is why we need a smoothed density field in the first place. When we smooth we are losing information at smaller scales and I don't see where introducing noise to the density field can be helpful. Could you perhaps provide some examples of questions and the smoothing scale that you would pick based on this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of three reasons for this smoothing:

1. The primordial matter density field is considered to be "almost" Gaussian. Thus, as a statistical motivation, smoothing can help us neglect the very local maxima/minima in this field.
2. Density contrast is a parameter mostly used for studies of Large-scale Structures (LSS). To address structures in the universe, we should specify a region. So, for studies related to structure formation, it would be necessary to define a spatial region and not just one point.
3. Practically, we can not measure the density contrast field with an "infinite" resolution. Thus, a smoothing is required for comparing theoretical analysis with observational results.